# missing class in first java program: MyFirstApp.java

Tags: java

I copied a simple java app from a book, but am getting a missing class error.

This is the app:

```
# cat MyFirstApp.java
public class MyFirstApp {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
       System.out.println("I Rule!");
       System.out.println("The World");
      }
}
```

It compiles:

```
[root@dev hfjava]# javac MyFirstApp.java
[root@dev hfjava]#
```

But when I go to run the program I get this error:

```
[root@dev hfjava]# java MyFirstApp.java
Error: Could not find or load main class MyFirstApp.java
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing the javac MyFirstApp.java correctly, but the reason it is not working when you actually try to run the program is because you are typing:

**java MyFirstApp.java**

when all you have to type is:

**java MyFirstApp**

Just leave out the .java extension when you actually run the program. Once you do this, your program should execute flawlessly! And remember, as long as you are a programmer, you do rule the world!

Write a comment if this doesn't work and I will continue to try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try `java -cp . MyFirstApp` as your command line.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `java MyFirstApp` in your command line after running the javac command.